# tcolorbox: change background of a part of the body

Tags: tcolorbox

I have a tcolorbox with various "part" separated by `\tcbline` and would like to change the background of two of the (e.g. the second and the forth. Has someone a good idea how to do it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1]
\tcbline
\lipsum[2]
\tcbline
\lipsum[1]
\tcbline
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tcbline` does not create 'functional' sub boxes, as `\tcblower` would do

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I know, but it should be possible to set nodes and draw the background with an overlay or something like this.

Comment: Yes, I had that in mind, but I am no expert in Ti*k*Z stuff. Thomas Sturm should know, I assume ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would do such stuff by using a `tcbraster` or `tcbitemize` inside an outer `tcolorbox`. The following code example creates colored stripes in blue and red, but every stripe could be given an individual color:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}%
\usepackage{lipsum,geometry}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,
      boxsep=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,leftupper=0pt,rightupper=0pt,
      toptitle=1mm,bottomtitle=1mm,lefttitle=5mm,righttitle=5mm,
      colbacktitle=yellow!20,coltitle=black,title=Box with interior raster,
      colback=blue!10,clip upper]
    \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=1,raster equal skip=0pt,
        sharp corners,boxrule=0pt,
        raster odd row/.style={empty},
        raster even row/.style={tile,colback=red!10}]
      \tcbitem
      \lipsum[1]
      \tcbitem
      \lipsum[2]
      \tcbitem
      \lipsum[1]
      \tcbitem
      \lipsum[1]
    \end{tcbitemize}
  \end{tcolorbox}


  \clearpage
  The same with a new environment:

  \newenvironment{mybox}{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,
      boxsep=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,leftupper=0pt,rightupper=0pt,
      toptitle=1mm,bottomtitle=1mm,lefttitle=5mm,righttitle=5mm,
      colbacktitle=yellow!20,coltitle=black,title=Box with interior raster,
      colback=blue!10,clip upper]%
    \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=1,raster equal skip=0pt,
        sharp corners,boxrule=0pt,
        raster odd row/.style={empty},
        raster even row/.style={tile,colback=red!10}]%
  }{\end{tcbitemize}\end{tcolorbox}}

  \begin{mybox}
    \tcbitem
    \lipsum[1]
    \tcbitem
    \lipsum[2]
    \tcbitem
    \lipsum[1]
    \tcbitem
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could it also be `raster even row/.style={empty,colback=red!10}`? The question is: what's `tile` does in even rows?

Comment: @Ignasi `empty` would remove all frames and backgrounds and the color would not show up. `tile` removes the frame completely to avoid previewer glitches with a `0pt` border. Here, alternatively to `tile`, you could use `frame hidden` or `frame engine=empty`.

Comment: This worked quite fine. It took me a bit time to figure out how to draw the lines (one has to exclude the first raster). Also I had an "equal height group" and so the background of the main box was seen at the bottom of some boxes but then it looked good. Thanks.

Comment: Is this environment breakable? (even if I add the breakable option, it does not break!)

Comment: `Breakable` works for me. Of course, only the outer box is breakable (`mybox`), the inner color blocks are not. So, you get breaks from one inner color block to another, but not inside a color block.